# Why WebWorker is firing several times on message event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous, web-worker

Trying to get image in base64 from web-worker. All is fine, except worker is replying several times to `.onmessage` event:

[image]

**main.js part:**

```
var worker = new Worker( 'js/ww.js' );
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log( e );
};
worker.postMessage( { url: '/api/aerial?x=159&y=94&zoom=8&base64=true' } );
```

**ww.js, WebWorker part:**

```
var self = this;

function makeRequest( url ) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ( !httpRequest ) {
        console.error( 'Giving up. Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance.' );
        return false;
    }

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var response = httpRequest.responseText;
        self.onMessage = postMessage( response );
    };

    httpRequest.open( 'GET', url, true );
    httpRequest.send();
}

self.addEventListener( 'message', function( event ) {
    makeRequest( event.data.url );
});
```

Why is it firing several times?

May it happened because of such native AJAX use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the correct state and status of the request.
In your `onreadystatechange`-handler you should do the following:

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var response = httpRequest.responseText;
        self.onMessage = postMessage( response );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! :) forgot about it, didn't use plain AJAX for a long time and now it's needed because jQuery can't be loaded in WebWorker instance, because WebWorker doesn't have window or document objects